# selenium cssSelector vs. tagName

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I have a use case that I need to find all iframe and object tags from the page.

Currently I'm using `cssSelector()` method. I have noticed that there is also `tagName()` method.

What is the difference between these 2 methods with the above use case ?

Comment: I guess the only difference will be that CSS selectors will give you far more flexibility on what you want to find, rather than tag name won't.

Answer (score 2):

`findElement(By.tagName("a_tag"))` will find elements by html tags such as `<iframe>` , `<div>`. But you can only provide it with html tags, not css classes, etc ...

With `findElement(By.cssSelector("a_tag"))` you can find elements with html tags but you can also give a css class for example `findElement(By.cssSelector("div.myClass"))`

For your case you can use :

```
List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"))
List<WebElement> objects = driver.findElements(By.tagName("object"))
```

And then perform a `for` loop to do your tests

Answer (score -2):

It's recommended to use cssSelector/id/xpath/etc ... By since it will wait for the "needed element" displayed if the element is not present on the page initially.

Because By.cssSelector is more specific, selenium will continue checking if the element exists until the implicit wait (x seconds) times out.

By.Tag is not specific at all. Using By.tagName, selenium will not wait for the element. On findElements(By.tagName("table"), Selenium will return an array of all the tables that are present immediately after the page loads. As the "needed" element is not present yet, it will not be in the array.

Comment: This is incorrect, `findElement` takes in consideration the implicit wait regardless of the identifier used.

Comment: @Arran, please re-read my comment

"if the element is not present on the page initially.", (such as as there are 10 other div elements on the page initially, and 11th <div> element display after 5s <-- the needed one, By.TagName only get 10 div elements and skip the 11th)

Comment: So would a CSS selector of `div` which is directly equivalent to `By.TagName("div")`. To do what you are describing your CSS selector would need to be `div:nth-of-type(11)` for it to physically wait until it has `11 `div`s on the page.

Comment: I totally agree with your comment about div:nth-of-type(11) for Css selector. And, By.TagName("div") will return a list of **10** div elements (and **skipped the needed** 11th element)

You can look back to my answer, that's why I said By.cssSelector is **more specific** and vice versa for By.TagName, especially for the case that our wanted element is not present on the page initially.